# Why $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{1+x}} $ is not uniformly convergent on $ \left(0,\;+\infty\right) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Why this series of functions is not uniformly convergent on $ \left(0,\;+\infty\right) $. \begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{1+x}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Have you tried something or do you wish us to do your homework?

Comment: Use the integral test for convergence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uniform convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{1+x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769124/uniform-convergence-of-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k1x)

Comment: There is this question about the same series: [Uniform convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{1+x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/769124). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%5E%7B1%2Bx%7D%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What do you think happens for $x\to 0^+$?

Comment: Yes I know it becomes a Harmonic series. But how can I show it is not uniformly convergent properly? For instance cauchy criterion

Comment: @Lithium: what [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_continuity) do uniformly convergent series have?

Answer (score 1):

This is the famous Riemann $\zeta$ function, shifted by 1 to the left: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

It is well-known that is has a singularity at 1 (in your notation due to the shift, at 0), and it is a simple pole. In other words, around 1, the $\zeta$ function around 1 "looks like" $1/(x-1)$. To make it more precise, $\zeta(x)-1/(x-1)$ is a smooth function on the positive half of the complex plane.

To translate all of this to your function: it has a simple pole at 0, and around 0, it looks like $1/x$, which is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: any simpler method? for instance using cauchy criterion?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{1+x}} >\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^{1+1/n}} >  \frac{n}{(2n)^{1+1/n}}$$

Comment: sorry did not get it. could you please explain thank you

Comment: Uniform convergence requires the LHS to converge to $0$. What does the lower bound on the RHS converge to?

Comment: Write what it means for a series to converge uniformly in your post and show it implies what I am stating.

Comment: Why hasn't this answer received more up votes?? Here is one (+1).

Comment: @MarkViola: Thanks for being so conscientious (as usual).

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Uniform convergence means that $$\sup_{x\in(0, +\infty)} \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^{1+x}} - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^{1+x}}\right| \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

As @RRL suggests, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ you can consider $x_n = \frac1n$ so

\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in(0, +\infty)} \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^{1+x}} - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^{1+x}}\right| &= \sup_{x\in(0, +\infty)} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^{1+x}} \\
&\ge \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^{1+\frac1n}}\\
&\ge \int_{n+1}^\infty \frac{dt}{t^{1+\frac1n}}\\
&= -\frac{n}{t^{1/n}} \Bigg|_{n+1}^\infty\\
&= \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n+1}}\\
&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} +\infty
\end{align}

so it doesn't converge to $0$.